# Custom post type won't take my custom fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-admin

I have written the following plugin:

```
    <?php

/* Set up the post types */
add_action( 'init', 'mdg_kjdz_register_post_types' );

/* Register the post types */
function mdg_kjdz_register_post_types() {

    /* Set up the arguments for the kjdz_adress post type */
    $adress_args = array(
            'public' => true,
            'query_var' => 'kjdz_adress',
            'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'adres',
                    'with_front' => false,
            ),
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'editor'
            ),
            'labels' => array(
                    'name' => 'Locaties',
                    'singular' => 'Locatie',
                    'add_new' => 'Voeg locatie toe',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Voeg locatie toe',
                    'edit_item' => 'Locatie aanpassen',
                    'new_item' => 'Nieuwe locatie',
                    'view_item' => 'Bekijk locatie',
                    'search_items' => 'Doorzoek locaties',
                    'not_found' => 'Geen locaties gevonden',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'Geen locaties in prullenbak'
            ),
    );

    /* Set up custom meta box kjdz_adress post type */
    $kjdz_adress_meta_box = array(
            'id' => 'adress-meta-box',
            'title' => 'Gegevens locatie',
            'page' => 'kjdz_adress',
            'context' => 'normal',
            'priority' => 'high',
            'fields'=> array(
                    array(
                            'name' => 'Adres',
                            'desc' => 'Adres locatie',
                            'id' => 'adress',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => 'Voer straatnaam en huisnummer in.'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => 'Plaatsnaam',
                            'desc' => 'Plaatsnaam locatie',
                            'id' => 'town',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => 'Voer de plaatsnaam in.'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => 'Soort locatie',
                            'id' => 'location_type',
                            'type' => 'radio',
                            'options' => array(
                                    array('name' => 'hoofdvestiging', 'value' => 'Hoofdvestiging'),
                                    array('name' => 'nevenvestiging', 'value' => 'Nevenvestiging')
                            )
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => 'Openingstijden',
                            'id' => 'opening_days1',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => array('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag')
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'id' => 'opening_days2',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => array('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag')
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'id' => 'opening_days3',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => array('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag')
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'id' => 'opening_days4',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => array('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag')
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'id' => 'opening_days5',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => array('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag')
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'id' => 'opening_days6',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => array('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag')
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'id' => 'opening_days7',
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => array('Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag', 'Zondag')
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de openingstijd in (vb. 09:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours1_1',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '09:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de sluitingstijd in (vb. 18:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours1_2',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '18:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de openingstijd in (vb. 09:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours2_1',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '09:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de sluitingstijd in (vb. 18:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours2_2',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '18:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de openingstijd in (vb. 09:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours3_1',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '09:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de sluitingstijd in (vb. 18:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours3_2',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '18:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de openingstijd in (vb. 09:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours4_1',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '09:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de sluitingstijd in (vb. 18:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours4_2',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '18:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de openingstijd in (vb. 09:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours5_1',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '09:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de sluitingstijd in (vb. 18:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours5_2',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '18:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de openingstijd in (vb. 09:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours6_1',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '09:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de sluitingstijd in (vb. 18:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours6_2',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => '18:00'
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de openingstijd in (vb. 09:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours7_1',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => ''
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => '',
                            'desc' => 'Voer de sluitingstijd in (vb. 18:00)',
                            'id' => 'opening_hours7_2',
                            'type' => 'text',
                            'std' => ''
                    )
                )
            );

            /* Register the post types */
            register_post_type( 'kjdz_adress', $adress_args );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'kjdz_adress_add_box');

/* Add meta box */
function kjdz_adress_add_box() {
        global $kjdz_adress_meta_box;

        add_meta_box($kjdz_adress_meta_box['id'], $kjdz_adress_meta_box['title'], 'kjdz_adress_show_box', $kjdz_adress_meta_box['page'], $kjdz_adress_meta_box['content'], $kjdz_adress_meta_box['priority']);
}

/* Callback function to show fields in meta box */
function kjdz_adress_show_box() {
    global $kjdz_adress_meta_box, $post;

    /* Use nonce for verification */
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="kjdz_adress_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)) ,'" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($kjdz_adress_meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
            /* Get current post meta data   */
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

            echo '<tr>',
                            '<th style="width: 20%;"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                            '<td>';
            switch ($field['type']) {
                    case 'text':
                            echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width: 97%" />', '<br />', $field['desc'];
                            break;
                    case 'textarea':
                            echo '<textarea name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="4" style="width: 97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea>', '<br />', $field['desc'];
                            break;
                    case 'select':
                            echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                                    echo '<option ', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                            }
                            echo '</select>';
                            break;
                    case 'radio':
                            foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                                    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option['value'], '"', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' checked="checked"' : '', '/>', $option['name'];
                            }
                            break;
                    case 'checkbox':
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', '/>';
                            break;
            }
            echo        '</td><td>',
                        '</td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}               

?>
```

Which shows up as the custom post type "kjdz_adress" or Locatie in the admin menu.

But my custom fields don't show up.
What am I missing?

Comment: use `add_meta_boxes` hook instead of `admin_menu`

Comment: That doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your `$kjdz_adress_meta_box` in one function, and referencing it in another. Just keep it in the function where you're trying to use it and that might fix it. Or define it elsewhere if you need it in more than one function. I don't think a `$global` call will necessarily transcend a function.

Comment: Should I declare the global $kjdz_adress_meta_box earlier?

Comment: Not sure why you're defining the `$kjdz_adress_meta_box` variable in the `register_post_type` function, as it's not used there. Beyond that, try to use a little debugging to see what's going on. Does the action get fired? Where in the chain does it break? Make sure you have debugging enabled and check your logs. Even if you don't see something there, you can use breadcrumbs like `file_put_contents()` to write where you are at in the chain of events. See where this is breaking.